# Extracting numbers from vectors of strings

Tags: regex, r

I have string like this:

```
years<-c("20 years old", "1 years old")
```

I would like to grep only the numeric number from this vector. Expected output is a vector:

```
c(20, 1)
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

How about

```
# pattern is by finding a set of numbers in the start and capturing them
as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", years))
```

or

```
# pattern is to just remove _years_old
as.numeric(gsub(" years old", "", years))
```

or

```
# split by space, get the element in first index
as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(years, " "), "[[", 1))
```

Comment: Why is the `.*` necessary? If you want them at the start, why not use `^[[:digit:]]+`?

Comment: `.*` is necessary as you need to match the entire string.  Without that, nothing is removed.  Also, note that `sub` can be used here instead of `gsub`.

Comment: if the number doesn't have to be in the start of the string, use this: `gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\\1", years)`

Comment: I want to get 27. I don't understand why, by adding conditions (such as adding an escaped "-", the result gets longer...
`gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*?", "\\1", "Jun. 27–30")` Result: [1] "2730"
`gsub(".*?([0-9]+)\\-.*?", "\\1", "Jun. 27–30")` Result: [1] "Jun. 27–30"

Answer (score 121):

**Update**
Since `extract_numeric` is deprecated, we can use `parse_number` from `readr` package.

```
library(readr)
parse_number(years)
```

Here is another option with `extract_numeric`

```
library(tidyr)
extract_numeric(years)
#[1] 20  1
```

Comment: Fine for this application but keep in mind `parse_number` does not play with negative numbers. Try  `parse_number("–27,633")`

Comment: @Nettle Yes, that is right and it won't work if there are multiple instances as well

Comment: The negative-number parsing bug has been fixed: https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/308  `readr::parse_number("-12,345") # [1] -12345`

Comment: extract_numeric is deprecated now and you will receive a warning to use readr::parse_number()

Comment: @NorthLattitude I did specified that in the `Update` if you noticed that

Answer (score 75):

I think that substitution is an indirect way of getting to the solution. If you want to retrieve all the numbers, I recommend `gregexpr`:

```
matches <- regmatches(years, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", years))
as.numeric(unlist(matches))
```

If you have multiple matches in a string, this will get all of them. If you're only interested in the first match, use `regexpr` instead of `gregexpr` and you can skip the `unlist`.

Comment: I didn't expect it, but this solution is slower than any of the others, by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg the `gregexpr`, `regexpr` or both?

Comment: `gregexpr`.  I hadn't tried `regexpr` until just now.  HUGE difference.  Using `regexpr` puts it between Andrew's and Arun's solutions (second fastest) on a 1e6 set.  Perhaps also interesting, using `sub` in Andrew's solution does not improve the speed.

Comment: This splits based on decimal points. For example 2.5 becomes c('2','5')

Comment: Replying to @MBorg changing the regular expression to `"-?[[:digit:]]+(\\.[[:digit:]]+)?"` I believe will account for negative numbers and decimals

Answer (score 58):

Or simply:

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", years))
# [1] 20  1
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer, it works fine!!

Comment: `\\D` is a metacharacter that matches non-digit characters: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_digit_non.asp

Answer (score 41):

Here's an alternative to Arun's first solution, with a simpler Perl-like regular expression:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]+", "", years, perl=TRUE))
```

Comment: `as.numeric(sub("\\D+","",years))`. If there were letters before and |or after, then `gsub`

Answer (score 30):

We can also use `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
years<-c("20 years old", "1 years old")
as.integer(stringr::str_extract(years, "\\d+"))
#[1] 20  1
```

If there are multiple numbers in the string and we want to extract all of them, we may use `str_extract_all` which unlike  `str_extract` returns all the macthes.

```
years<-c("20 years old and 21", "1 years old")
stringr::str_extract(years, "\\d+")
#[1] "20"  "1"

stringr::str_extract_all(years, "\\d+")

#[[1]]
#[1] "20" "21"

#[[2]]
#[1] "1"
```

Answer (score 26):

A `stringr` pipelined solution:

```
library(stringr)
years %>% str_match_all("[0-9]+") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, but this answer does not extract the negative signs before the numbers in the string.

Answer (score 18):

You could get rid of all the letters too:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", years))
```

Likely this is less generalizable though.

Comment: Oddly, Andrew's solution beats this by a factor of 5 on my machine.

Answer (score 8):

Extract numbers from any string at beginning position.

```
x <- gregexpr("^[0-9]+", years)  # Numbers with any number of digits
x2 <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(years, x)))
```

Extract numbers from any string INDEPENDENT of position.

```
x <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", years)  # Numbers with any number of digits
x2 <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(years, x)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the package *unglue* we can do :

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)

years<-c("20 years old", "1 years old")
unglue_vec(years, "{x} years old", convert = TRUE)
#> [1] 20  1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

More info: https://github.com/moodymudskipper/unglue/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 5):

After the post from **Gabor Grothendieck** [post at the r-help mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-June/355435.html)

```
years<-c("20 years old", "1 years old")

library(gsubfn)
pat <- "[-+.e0-9]*\\d"
sapply(years, function(x) strapply(x, pat, as.numeric)[[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in this question as it applies to extracting values from the `base::summary()` function. Another option you might want to consider to extract values from a table is to build a function that takes any entry of your `summary()` table and transforms it into a useful number. For example if you get:

```
(s <- summary(dataset))

sv_final_num_beneficiarios  sv_pfam_rec        sv_area_transf    
Min.   :    1.0            Min.   :0.0000036   Min.   :0.000004  
1st Qu.:   67.5            1st Qu.:0.0286363   1st Qu.:0.010107  
Median :  200.0            Median :0.0710803   Median :0.021865  
Mean   :  454.6            Mean   :0.1140274   Mean   :0.034802  
3rd Qu.:  515.8            3rd Qu.:0.1527177   3rd Qu.:0.044234  
Max.   :17516.0            Max.   :0.8217923   Max.   :0.360924
```

you might want to extract that `1st Qu` for `sv_pfam_rec` and for that read the 2nd row of the 2nd col. In order to get the formatted single value I made a function

```
s_extract <- function(summary_entry){
separate(as_tibble(summary_entry),
sep = ":",
col = value, 
remove = FALSE, 
into = c("bad", "good"))[[3]] %>% 
as.numeric() 
}
```

You just have to feed a summary entry, for example `summary_entry = s[3,3]` to obtain the `Median` of `sv_area_transf`.

It is worth nothing that given that this function is based on `separate()` it makes it easier to navigate certain cases in which the name of the variable also contains numbers

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on some other very good answers:

```r
years <- c("20 years old", "1 years old")

as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", years))
#> [1] 20  1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Here we use `^` at the beginning of the `regex` to negate the pattern.