# Extracting unique numbers from string in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of strings which contain random characters such as:

```
list=list()
list[1] = "djud7+dg[a]hs667"
list[2] = "7fd*hac11(5)"
list[3] = "2tu,g7gka5"
```

I'd like to know which numbers are present at least once (`unique()`) in this list. The solution of my example is:

solution:  `c(7,667,11,5,2)`

If someone has a method that does not consider 11 as "eleven" but as "one and one", it would also be useful. The solution in this condition would be:

solution:   `c(7,6,1,5,2)`

(I found this post on a related subject: [Extracting numbers from vectors of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings))

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For the second answer, you can use `gsub` to remove everything from the string that's not a number, then split the string as follows:

```
unique(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[^0-9]", "", unlist(ll)), ""))))
# [1] 7 6 1 5 2
```

For the first answer, similarly using `strsplit`,

```
unique(na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(unlist(ll), "[^0-9]+")))))
# [1]   7 667  11   5   2
```

PS: don't name your variable `list` (as there's an inbuilt function `list`). I've named your data as `ll`.

Answer (score 17):

Here is yet another answer, this one using `gregexpr` to find the numbers, and `regmatches` to extract them:

```
l <- c("djud7+dg[a]hs667", "7fd*hac11(5)", "2tu,g7gka5")

temp1 <- gregexpr("[0-9]", l)   # Individual digits
temp2 <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", l)  # Numbers with any number of digits

as.numeric(unique(unlist(regmatches(l, temp1))))
# [1] 7 6 1 5 2
as.numeric(unique(unlist(regmatches(l, temp2))))
# [1]   7 667  11   5   2
```

Answer (score 9):

## A solution using  [stringi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html)

```
 # extract the numbers:

 nums <- stri_extract_all_regex(list, "[0-9]+")

 # Make vector and get unique numbers:

 nums <- unlist(nums)
 nums <- unique(nums)
```

And that's your first solution

[image: Screenshot from on-liner in R]

For the second solution I would use `substr`:

```
nums_first <- sapply(nums, function(x) unique(substr(x,1,1)))
```

Comment: Where does `stri_extract_all_regex()` come from?

Comment: The stringi package, like it says in the title

Answer (score 7):

You could use `?strsplit` (like suggested in @Arun's answer in [Extracting numbers from vectors (of strings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings)):

```
l <- c("djud7+dg[a]hs667", "7fd*hac11(5)", "2tu,g7gka5")

## split string at non-digits
s <- strsplit(l, "[^[:digit:]]")

## convert strings to numeric ("" become NA)
solution <- as.numeric(unlist(s))

## remove NA and duplicates
solution <- unique(solution[!is.na(solution)])
# [1]   7 667  11   5   2
```

Answer (score 6):

A `stringr` solution with `str_match_all` and piped operators. For the first solution:

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all(ll, "[0-9]+") %>% unlist %>% unique %>% as.numeric
```

Second solution:

```
str_match_all(ll, "[0-9]") %>% unlist %>% unique %>% as.numeric
```

(Note: I've also called the list `ll`)

Answer (score 1):

Use strsplit using pattern as the inverse of numeric digits: 0-9

For the example you have provided, do this:

```
tmp <- sapply(list, function (k) strsplit(k, "[^0-9]"))
```

Then simply take a union of all `sets' in the list, like so:

```
tmp <- Reduce(union, tmp)
```

Then you only have to remove the empty string.

Comment: Three identical answers in a minute of each other! :D

Comment: `strsplit` is vectorised. You could/should avoid using loops by `unlist`ing  OP's data.

Comment: Using `Reduce` with `union` (is essentially looping) here will also be very time consuming on huge lists (`unique` and `unlist` would be much faster).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `str_extract_numbers()` function from the `strex` package.

```r
pacman::p_load(strex)
list=list()
list[1] = "djud7+dg[a]hs667"
list[2] = "7fd*hac11(5)"
list[3] = "2tu,g7gka5"
charvec <- unlist(list)
print(charvec)
#> [1] "djud7+dg[a]hs667" "7fd*hac11(5)"     "2tu,g7gka5"
str_extract_numbers(charvec)
#> [[1]]
#> [1]   7 667
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  7 11  5
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 2 7 5
unique(unlist(str_extract_numbers(charvec)))
#> [1]   7 667  11   5   2
```

Created on 2018-09-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).