# r import data column with occasional unknown strings

Tags: r, import

Using R, I'm importing large .csv datasets in a data frame.  My problem is that some of my numeric data columns contain the occasional character string.

```
 thisData["colName"] <- lapply(thisData["colName"],as.numeric)
```

doesn't work.  Neither does this:

```
thisData["colName"] <- as.integer(thisData["colName"])
```

I would like to just set any strings in the numeric data columns to NA.  Any easy way to do this without nested for loops going through every entry looking for something that looks like a string?

Comment: this was asked several times in SO. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17009777/640783).

Comment: You can do either `thisData$colName <- as.numeric(thisData$colName)` or `thisData[["colName"]] <- as.numeric(thisData[["colName"]])` (note the double brackets).

Comment: Thanks guys - thisData[["colName"]] <- as.numeric(thisData[["colName"]]) worked great.

Answer (score 1):

may many options. I like the way stringr deal with this:

```
vec <- c('a1', 1, 'a', '01', '1a')
library(stringr)
str_extract(vec, "[[:digit:]]+")
#[1] "1"  "1"  NA   "01" "1"

vec <- c('a10', 10, 'a', '0101', '10a')
as.numeric(str_extract(vec, "[[:digit:]]+"))
#[1]  10  10  NA 101  10
```