# create new column of parsed text

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I would like to parse the "text" column and create a new column that is the number that starts in the 4th position and ends before the 1st underscore. The number will be either 1 or 2 digits. Here is an example:

```
d = data.frame(group = c("A","b","C"),text =c("DDD10_sdfdsdsfads_","ggg8_dsfsd_","hhh1_dsfdsaf_dsafdafd"))
d
```

see the new column below that i'd like to create

```
  group                  text     NEW COLUMN ??
1     A    DDD10_sdfdsdsfads_          10
2     b           ggg8_dsfsd_           8
3     C hhh1_dsfdsaf_dsafdafd           1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's what I did - not sure if it's the best way, but I referenced
[Extracting unique numbers from string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009628/extracting-numbers-from-string-in-r)
and worked this up.

```
d = data.frame(group = c("A","b","C"),text =c("DDD10_sdfdsdsfads_","ggg8_dsfsd_","hhh1_dsfdsaf_dsafdafd"))

d$newColumn <- gsub('[^0-9]', '', d$text)

> d
  group                  text newColumn
1     A    DDD10_sdfdsdsfads_        10
2     b           ggg8_dsfsd_         8
3     C hhh1_dsfdsaf_dsafdafd         1
```

Answer (score 0):

As the start and end position are known, we can extract using `substr` and then remove the `_`

```
 d$newColumn <- as.numeric(sub("_", "", substr(d$text, 4, 5)))
 d$newColumn
 #[1] 10  8  1
```

---

Or with `sub` alone

```
as.numeric(sub("^.{3}(.{1,2})_.*", "\\1", d$text))
#[1] 10  8  1
```