# regular expression in R, match substring only if things after

Tags: regex, r

```
my_string = "2011, this year I made 750,000 dollars"
```

Is there an elegant way to match `"2011"` and `"750,000"` in the string above. The idea is to extract numeric values when it looks like to numeric values, i.e. `\d+` or `\d+[\.,]?\d*` depending on the presence of a comma after

I tried this but it doesn't match exactly what I wanted, I got "2011," which is no good

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all(fkin, "(\\d+[\\.,]?\\d*)
```

Here is my expected resut:

```
"2011" "750,000"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009628/extracting-numbers-from-string-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)*
```

It's very elegant, I tried it in front of a mirror.

Comment: sorry it works, thk u, did not know about the nested parenthesis

Comment: @ casimir, sorry what the meaning of ?:

Comment: sorry to ask again but what if for a reason "750,000-589" is a a substring and I don't want to match it because it looks more to phone number or a reference?

Comment: @hansglick: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, but reading a basic regex tutorial will avoid you a lot of problems.

Comment: @hansglick: about the problem of phone numbers, I suggest to add `(-[0-9]+)?` at the end of the pattern. Then you can filter items in results when the capture group exists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one regex **pure base R** approach to extract integer or float values that are not part of the string of digits separated with a hyphen:

```
> str <- "2011, this year I made 750,000 dollars and 750,000-589 here"
> regmatches(str, gregexpr('(?<!\\d-)\\b\\d+(?:[,.]\\d+)?+(?!-)', str, perl=T))[[1]]
[1] "2011"    "750,000"
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/xJ0D2m) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM9uZ4/1).
Since the regex contains lookarounds, you need to specify the `perl=TRUE` argument.

**Pattern explanation**:

- `(?<!\d-)` - a negative lookbehind failing the match when a digit with a hyhen precedes the current location
- `\b\d+` - a word boundary (before the next digit, there cannot be a word char - letter, digit or `_`)
- `(?:[,.]\d+)?+` - a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) matching 1 or 0 sequences of a comma or dot (`[,.]`) followed with 1 or more digits (and this sequence is matched possessively (see `?+`) so that the regex engine did not check for a hyphen after `\b\d+`)
- `(?!-)` - a negative loookahead that fails the match if there is a hyphen after the digits detected.