# R extract numeric values from text

Tags: r

Using R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06):

When UIM (unique identifying marker), what is the recommended approach for extracting the numeric portion of the string of text? Also, I don't to extract the numeric portion when BAD is present.

```
text_entry<-rbind("Text words UIM 1234, 5678, 9012. More text and words.", #1
      "Text words UIM 2143 6589 1032. More text and words.", #2
    "Text words UIMs 4123 and 8657 and more text and words.", #3
    "Text words BAD 4123 and 8657 and more text and words.", #4
    "Text words UIM-2143, UIM-6589, and UIM-1032. More text and words.", #5
    "Text words BAD-2143, BAD-6589, and BAD-1032. More text and words.", #6
    "Text words UIM that follow: 2143, 6589, and UIM-1032. More text and words.", #7
    "Text words UIM that follow: 2143 1032. More text and words.") #8
```

Extract_desired:

```
1234, 5678, 9012 #1
2143, 6589, 1032 #2
4123, 8657 #3
NA (due to BAD) #4
2143, 6589, 1032 #5
NA (due to BAD) #6
2143, 6589, 1032 #7
2143,  1032 #8
```

Unfortunately, I need to maintain traceability back to the row number, i.e. know which rows provided UIM info and which ones didn't.

Thanks a ton for any feedback and info.

Comment: If possible, it is desired to not have to rely on a package, but if that is the best way, so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package `stringr`, here the result is a list but it gives what you want :

```
library(stringr)
extract_desired <- lapply(text_entry, function(x) {if (!grepl("BAD", x)) unlist(str_extract_all(x, "\\d+"))})
extract_desired[c(1,4)] 

## [[1]]
## [1] "1234" "5678" "9012"

## [[2]]
## NULL
```

If you want to know which row don't provide info, you can use :

```
which(sapply(extract_desired, is.null))
## [1] 4 6
```

**EDIT :**

If you don't want to use `stringr`, you can do like sebastian-c say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings) :

```
extract_desired <- lapply(text_entry, function(x) {if (!grepl("BAD", x)) unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", x)))})
```

Comment: > install.packages("stringr")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning messages:
1: In open.connection(con, "r") : unable to resolve 'cran.r-project.org'
2: package ‘stringr’ is not available (for R version 3.0.3) 
>

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an answer applicable to R version 3.0.3?

Comment: `stringr` is available for R 3.0.3 or R 3.1.0, it's an internet problem.