# Remove first X characters in a data.frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like below,

DATA[,1]

```
Price=100
Price=200
Price=300
```

DATA[,2]

```
Size=10
Size=20
Size=30
```

What's the easy way I can remove the character part then do the calculation directly.

I would expect to have result like:

```
100*10
200*20
300*30
```

Comment: So... almost this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings
Are the strings constant?

Comment: `tidyr::extract_numeric(DATA[,1]) * tidyr::extract_numeric(DATA[,2])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `df$c1 <- gsub("Size=", "", df$c1)` on both columns to remove the characters
2. Use `df$c1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$c1))` on both columns to change to numeric
3. `df$c3 <- df$c1*df$c2` will work to multiply the columns and create a new column of answers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `substring` to get right of the left hand side of each column.

The assumption is here that the part you want to cut out (e.g. "Price=") has the same length within one column while the length of the numeric value at the end can vary (e.g. "100" or "1000000").

```
# Create sample data
d <- data.frame(column1=c("Price=100", "Price=200", "Price=300", "Price=400"),
                column2=c("Size=10","Size=20","Size=30", "Size=40"),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Transform and multiply columns
d$result <- as.numeric(substring(d[,1], 7, nchar(d[,1]))) * 
            as.numeric(substring(d[,2], 6, nchar(d[,2])))

# Result
# > d
# column1     column2 result
# 1 Price=100 Size=10   1000
# 2 Price=200 Size=20   4000
# 3 Price=300 Size=30   9000
# 4 Price=400 Size=40  16000
```