# In R is there a way to extract data based on the beginning and end of a pattern but not the middle data?

Tags: r, regex, string, match

In R is there a way to extract data based on the beginning and end of a pattern but not the middle data?

ie. if the following was in a single cell

```
(1) Number = '1111111111, 0000000000' Text =....
(2) Number = '0000000000' Text =....
```

it would result in:

```
(1) 1111111111, 0000000000
(2) 0000000000
```

I tried:

```
x1<-str_match(x,"(?<=Number'\\s\\=\\s\\')(\\d|\\s|\\,)\\d\\'")
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting numbers from vectors of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings)

Comment: Please explain what exact requirements and string input look like, it is not clear from what you showed in the question. `str_match` is a good candidate here, but it seems you need `str_match_all(x, "(?:Number\\s*=\\s*'|\\G(?!\\A)\\s*,\\s*)(\\d+)")` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/X7Rmb7/1)). And grab Group 1 contents.

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]+"), toString)
#[1] "1111111111, 0000000000" "0000000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a PCRE regex to extract the numbers after `Number='` from your input text:

```
(?:Number\s*=\s*'|\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*)\K\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tb0QqF/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:Number\s*=\s*'|\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*)`  - either of the two alternatives:

  - `Number\s*=\s*'` - `Number` and a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `|` - or
  - `\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*` - end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) and a comma enclosed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`)
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `\d+` - 1+ digits (returned as a match)

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/ysAPXx):

```
> x <- c("(1) Number = '1111111111, 0000000000' Text =....", "(2) Number = '0000000000' Text =....")
> regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?:Number\\s*=\\s*'|\\G(?!\\A)\\s*,\\s*)\\K\\d+", x, perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "1111111111" "0000000000"

[[2]]
[1] "0000000000"
```