# Text-mining including patterns and numbers

Tags: r, regex, match, text-mining

Dataset contains a free text field with information on building plans. I need to split the content of the field in 2 parts, the first part contains only the number of planned buildings, the other only the type of building. I have a reference lexicon list with the types of buildings.

**Example**

```
Plans<- c("build 10 houses ","5 luxury apartments with sea view", 
          "renovate 20 cottages"," transform 2 bungalows and a school", "1 hotel")
```

**Reference list**

```
Types <-c("houses", "cottages", "bungalows", "luxury apartments")
```

**Desired Output** 2 colums, Number and Type, with this content:

```
Number  Type
10  houses
5   apartments
20  cottages
2   bungalows
```

**Tried**

```
matches <- unique (grep(paste(Types,collapse="|"), Plans, value=TRUE))
```

I can match the `plans` and `types`, but I can’t extract the numbers and types into two columns.

I tried `str_split_fixed` and `grepl` using `:digit:` and `:alpha:` but it isn’t working.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is only going to be one numeric part in the string, we can extract the numeric part by replacing all the characters to empty strings. We create the `Type` column by extracting any of the string present in the `Plans`.

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(Number = as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", Plans)), 
           Type = str_extract(Plans, paste(Types,collapse="|")))

#  Number              Type
#1     10            houses
#2      5 luxury apartments
#3     20          cottages
#4      2         bungalows
#5      1              <NA>
```

For the 5th row, "hotel" is not present in `Types` so it gives output as `NA`, if you need to ignore such cases you can do it with `is.na`. Extracting number from the string part is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings/14543839#14543839).

Comment: Thanks Ronak, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `strcapture` from base R:

```
strcapture(pattern = paste0("(\\d+)\\s(",paste(Types,collapse="|"),")"),x = Plans,
           proto = data.frame(Number=numeric(),Type=character()))

  Number              Type
1     10            houses
2      5 luxury apartments
3     20          cottages
4      2         bungalows
5     NA              <NA>
```