# Extract numeric characters from cells in a data frame in R

Tags: r, extract, data-science, data-cleaning

I'm trying to extract the numeric values from a data frame like this:

```
ID Secc                     col1      col2        col3
 1 Sección 0805601006       1400      1300        85*      
 2 Sección 0805601007       1475      1365        5.0     
 3 Sección 0805601005       760       760         0.0      
 4 Sección 0805601003       1335      1335        0.0      
 5 Sección 0805601002       655       655         0.0      
 6 Sección 0805601004       900       815         85*
```

To get a "clean" data frame only with nyumeric characters like this:

```
    ID Secc             col1      col2       col3
     1 0805601006       1400      1300       85      
     2 0805601007       1475      1365       5.0     
     3 0805601005       760       760        0.0      
     4 0805601003       1335      1335       0.0      
     5 0805601002       655       655        0.0      
     6 0805601004       900       815        85
```

I've been trying many functions like `extract_numeric, st_replace, gsub` and so on, but can't get the result that I would like to get.

Does anyone knows how can I clean my data?

Comment: `as.numeric(substr(df$Secc, 8, length(df$Secc)))`?

Comment: showing the result you expect to get would be helpful ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting numbers from vectors of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings)

Answer (score 9):

you can use `readr::parse_number` :

```
library(readr)
df1[] <- lapply(df1, parse_number)
df1
#   ID     Secc col1 col2 col3
# 1  1 8.06e+08 1400 1300   85
# 2  2 8.06e+08 1475 1365    5
# 3  3 8.06e+08  760  760    0
# 4  4 8.06e+08 1335 1335    0
# 5  5 8.06e+08  655  655    0
# 6  6 8.06e+08  900  815   85

sapply(df1,class)
#        ID      Secc      col1      col2      col3 
# "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

In tidyspeak, use `df1 |> mutate(across(everything(), parse_number))`

Here's a way in base R (same output):

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("(?![\\.-])\\D","",x, perl=T)))
```

Note: `tidyr::extract_numeric` will work as well, but it's deprecated in favor of `readr::parse_number`.

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="ID Secc                     col1      col2        col3
1 'Sección 0805601006'       1400      1300        85*      
2 'Sección 0805601007'       1475      1365        5.0     
3 'Sección 0805601005'       760       760         0.0      
4 'Sección 0805601003'       1335      1335        0.0      
5 'Sección 0805601002'       655       655         0.0      
6 'Sección 0805601004'       900       815         85*",h=T,strin=F)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's think of a more general approach. Numbers can be negative (-).

I have changed the data a little bit.

```
    df1 <- read.table(text="ID Secc                     col1      col2        col3
1 'Sección 0805601006'       1400      1300        85*      
                  2 'Sección 0805601007'       -14rofl75      1365        5.0     
                  3 'Sección 0805601005'       760       760         0.0      
                  4 'Sección 0805601003'       1-3-3-5      1335        0.0      
                  5 'Sección 0805601002'       -655       HEHE-655         0.0      
                  6 'Sección 0805601004'       900       815         85*",h=T,strin=F)
```

code:

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
    ge<-gregexpr("(^-?|(?<=\\D)-)?(\\d\\.?\\d*?)+",x,perl=T)
    return(as.numeric(sapply(regmatches(x,ge),paste0,collapse="")))
    }
df1[] <- lapply(df1,fun1)
```

result:

```
#  ID       Secc  col1 col2 col3
#1  1 0805601006  1400 1300   85
#2  2 0805601007 -1475 1365    5
#3  3 0805601005   760  760    0
#4  4 0805601003  1335 1335    0
#5  5 0805601002  -655 -655    0
#6  6 0805601004   900  815   85
```