# Modify value of column in data.table without loop

Tags: r, data.table

I have a datatable which looks like the following

```
> head(mydt)
    name  b      c
1:  ao    2      1 GiB
2:  bo    2      1.4 Gib
```

Now, I try to do some cleansing - i try to remove the unit from the values in column c without any loops,..
I did the following:

```
mydt[,4 :=substr(c,0,gregexpr(pattern=' ',c)[[1]][1]-1)]
```

What I get is something like this:

```
> head(mydt)
    name  b      c
1:  ao    2      1 G
2:  bo    2      1.4
```

What I expect is the following

```
> head(mydt)
    name  b      c
1:  ao    2      1
2:  bo    2      1.4
```

However, it doesn't work --> it seems to use the same endpoint for all values. What I am doing wrong? How can I access the "current" value?

Comment: my question is not about extracting numbers from vectors -> it is about how to access the current value in order to modify it!

Comment: "_i try to remove the unit from the values in column c_" can easily be interpreted as that you want to remove the unit, i.e. extract the number ;) Given your LHS of `:=`, it seems like you need to study `?:=` and an introductory data.table text.

Comment: you are right, I clarified my question!

Comment: [Extracting numbers from vectors of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` on a `data.table` object, which evaluates each value individually as opposed to just the first row. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

mydt<-data.table(name = c('ao','bo'), b = c(2,2), c = c("1 GiB", "1.4 GiB"))
mydt %>% 
  mutate(d = as.numeric(gsub(" GiB","",c)))

  name b       c   d
1   ao 2   1 GiB 1.0
2   bo 2 1.4 GiB 1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydt <- data.table(name = c("ao","bo"),
                   b = c(2,2),
                   c = c("1 GiB", "1.4 Gib"))
```

We can take several approaches.

Using tidyverse:

```
mydt %>% mutate(c = parse_number(c))
```

Or,

```
mydt %>% separate(col = c,into = "c",sep = " ",convert = T)
```

Using data.table approach

```
mydt[,
     c := tstrsplit(c," ", fixed = TRUE, keep = 1L)]
```

which gives output with column c as character.

To get c as a numeric output:

```
mydt[,
     c := tstrsplit(c," ", fixed = TRUE, keep = 1L)
     ][,
       c := as.numeric(c)]
```

Your original code can be replaced by below code:

```
mydt[, c :=substr(c,0,str_start(c," "))]
```