# Is it possible to take information from the title of a file?

Tags: r

I have this big script with some plot titles that I would just change like the date and time depending on the data I'm working with read.csv. I am already using paste("title",variable,"title") on the title so I just need to change the variable on the beggining of the script, but I've been thinking if there is a way to use the title of the csv file to define these variables while reading.

What I mean, if I'm not very clear, is something like:

I have this data from January 15 2020 saved as **"data20200115.txt"**
Instead of changing the variable **"date"** that I defined to write every plot title of the script with

```
main=paste("Date:",date)
```

I want to take the **"20200115"** from the title of the .txt and put it in the variable **"date"**. Is this possible?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: you can extract numbers only using this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings then you can format them with `as.Date`?

Comment: `date <- gsub("\\D", "", "data20200115.txt")`

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a variable `filename` where you store the string "data20200115.txt"

You can use base R or any library that allows you to use regex
Here is a solution with `stringr`

```
filename= "data20200115.txt" 
library(stringr)
date = str_match(filename,'data(.*).txt')[,2]
```

Basically it's saying 'give me everything that's between "data" and ".txt" in filename'