# How to extract a number before a pattern in a string

Tags: r

I have sentences like this:

```
string <- "This is: the first/ part 123 EUR then the second part."
```

Could anyone help me to extract "123" after "EUR" from the string, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Lots of ideas on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14543627/5325862) for example—any of those work?

Comment: thank you very much. I've solved it with the help of @akrun already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear about the pattern, if it is `EUR`, then

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, "\\d+(?= EUR)")
#[1] "123"
```

In the updated string, it can be

```
string <- "Time Interval [08:00-20:00]1,3 EUR/min." 
str_extract(string, "\\d+(,\\d+)?(?= EUR)")
#[1] "1,3"
```

Comment: string <- "Time Interval [08:00-20:00]1,3 EUR/min."

Comment: @Liselotte  What is the expected output

Comment: I want to get "1,3"

Comment: could you please explain what "\\d+(,\\d+)?(?= EUR)" means?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you would like:

```
gsub( "[0-9]" , "", "This is: the first/ part 123 EUR then the second part." )
```

If you want to keep the numbers:

```
stringr::str_extract(  "This is: the first/ part 123 EUR then the second part." ,"[0-9]+" )
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `sub` to extract a number with an optional comma and another number followed by `"EUR"`

```
string <- "This is: the first/ part 123 EUR then the second part." 
sub(".*?(\\d+(,\\d+)?)\\s+EUR.*", "\\1", string)
#[1] "123"
```

Same pattern can be used for the updated string as well.

```
string <- "Time Interval [08:00-20:00]1,3 EUR/min." 
sub(".*?(\\d+(,\\d+)?)\\s+EUR.*", "\\1", string)
#[1] "1,3"
```