# How to extract the text in the string using regular expression?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I crawled a following text from websites:

```
\n\tsfw=1;\n\tcaptions=[[\"2017-05\",2850],[\"2017-06\",3450],[\"2017-07\",3350],[\"2017-08\",3650],[\"2017-09\",4250],[\"2017-10\",4600],[\"2017-11\",4750],[\"2017-12\",5500],[\"2018-01\",7300],[\"2018-02\",7700],[\"2018-03\",11350],[\"2018-04\",10900],[\"2018-05\",11500],[\"2018-06\",10800],[\"2018-07\",13200],[\"2018-08\",14200],[\"2018-09\",15900],[\"2018-10\",19700],[\"2018-11\",21800],[\"2018-12\",18300],[\"2019-01\",18550],[\"2019-02\",18150],[\"2019-03\",18050],[\"2019-04\",18850],[\"2019-05\",71000],[\"2019-06\",83200],[\"2019-07\",72650],[\"2019-08\",80400],[\"2019-09\",100600],[\"2019-10\",114000],[\"2019-11\",110250],[\"2019-12\",107100],[\"2020-01\",116050],[\"2020-02\",117950],[\"2020-03\",145350]];\n
```

I want to extract the text like the numeric "2850", "3450", etc.. Could you show how to write the regular expression for this? Thanks.

Here is the code for crawling the text in r:

```
webpage <- read_html("https://imgflip.com/meme/Drake-Hotline-Bling")
text <- html_nodes(webpage,xpath = '//script') %>% html_text()
text <- text[8]
```

Comment: Please add string as `dput` which we could copy/paste into our R sessions. Probably this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_match_all` from the `stringr` package. This will look for everything in between the two delimiters you choose (in this case I chose `\",` and `]`).

The generic form of this function is: `stringr::str_match_all(vector, "delimiter(.*?)delimiter")` (note use `stringr::str_match` to only match the first instanct)

```
vec <- '\n\tsfw=1;\n\tcaptions=[[\"2017-05\",2850],[\"2017-06\",3450],[\"2017-07\",3350],[\"2017-08\",3650],[\"2017-09\",4250],[\"2017-10\",4600],[\"2017-11\",4750],[\"2017-12\",5500],[\"2018-01\",7300],[\"2018-02\",7700],[\"2018-03\",11350],[\"2018-04\",10900],[\"2018-05\",11500],[\"2018-06\",10800],[\"2018-07\",13200],[\"2018-08\",14200],[\"2018-09\",15900],[\"2018-10\",19700],[\"2018-11\",21800],[\"2018-12\",18300],[\"2019-01\",18550],[\"2019-02\",18150],[\"2019-03\",18050],[\"2019-04\",18850],[\"2019-05\",71000],[\"2019-06\",83200],[\"2019-07\",72650],[\"2019-08\",80400],[\"2019-09\",100600],[\"2019-10\",114000],[\"2019-11\",110250],[\"2019-12\",107100],[\"2020-01\",116050],[\"2020-02\",117950],[\"2020-03\",145350]];\n'

stringr::str_match_all(vec, "\",(.*?)]")[[1]][, 2]
[1]  "2850"   "3450"   "3350"   "3650"   "4250"   "4600"   "4750"   "5500"   "7300"   "7700"   "11350"  "10900"  "11500"  "10800"  "13200"  "14200"  "15900" 
[18] "19700"  "21800"  "18300"  "18550"  "18150"  "18050"  "18850"  "71000"  "83200"  "72650"  "80400"  "100600" "114000" "110250" "107100" "116050" "117950"
[35] "145350"
```

Comment: If this answered your question feel free to mark the question as answered by clicking the tick mark below the voting arrows. This can assist future users looking for answers