# How to remove part of string value in column using stringr library?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, stringr

I have a dataframe with a column:

```
value-1245
value-4578
value-9976
```

I want to remove "value-" from it and turn it into numeric. So desired result is:

```
1245
4578
9976
```

How to do that? I tried `str_replace(column1, "value-", "")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting numbers from vectors of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_remove` which is shortcut for `str_replace` with empty replacement (`""`)

```
as.numeric(stringr::str_remove(df$column1, "value-"))
```

Or in base R -

```
as.numeric(sub("value-", "", df$column1))
```

Comment: and how to do it in pipeline? cause when I use it in pipeline, it says that object column1 not found. I use it as ```%>% as.numeric(stringr::str_remove(column1, "value-"))```

Comment: If your dataframe is called `df` and column as `column1` you can do - `df %>% mutate(column1 = as.numeric(stringr::str_remove(column1, "value-")))`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `trimws` in `base R`

```
as.numeric(trimws(df$column1, whitespace = "value-"))
```

Or with `readr::parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number(df$column1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `extract_numeric` function from `tidyr` package and combine witth `abs` to remove the minus sign:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(column1 = abs(extract_numeric(column1)))
```

Output:

```
  column1
1    1245
2    4578
3    9976
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(column1 = c("value-1245", "value-4578","value-9976"))
```