# Extract numbers that appear last in the string

Tags: r

Is there a way to extract numbers from the strings that appear last

```
asd <- c("asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf654")
asd1 <- c("asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf65421")
```

Expected output

```
new_asd 
654

new_asd1
65421
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting numbers from vectors of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings)

Comment: No No. The thing is, only the numbers that appear at the last need to be extracted

Comment: Are there any strings that do not end in a number?  If so, how do you hope to handle them? Do you want to return NA, or to return the number that is closest to the end?  If the former then the regex will need `$` in it.  Many of the answer below will give you the latter result.

Answer (score 4):

This code extracts always the last numeric entries in a string:

```
(stringr::str_extract(asd, stringr::regex("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)")))
"654"
(stringr::str_extract(asd1, stringr::regex("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)")))
"65421"
```

If you want to get only the number when the very last character of the string is a number then you could implement a simple ifelse condition to check for that specifically, e.g.:

```
x<- c("asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf654f")
ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(substr(x, nchar(x), nchar(x)))), 
       (stringr::str_extract(x, stringr::regex("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)"))),
       NA)
NA #returns NA because last entry of string is not numeric ("f")
```

Comment: Your regex incorrectly extracts "1" from "a1a".

Comment: I've added an ifelse condition to account for that as an extension of my code. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

A single regex is sufficient for your situation.

```
stringr::str_extract(asd, "(\\d+$)")
```

The `$` anchors the capture group to the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sub` combined with `ifelse` here:

```r
x <- c("asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf654", "abc", "123")
nums <- ifelse(grepl("\\d$", x), sub(".*?(\\d+)$", "\\1", x), "")
nums

[1] "654" ""    "123"
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution which first splits the string based on whitespace, then gets the last substring and removes any letters. This should work as long as there is only letters and numbers in the strings.

```
library(stringr)

get_num = function(x) {
    str_remove_all(rev(unlist(str_split(x, " ")))[1], "[a-z]")
}
```

```
> get_num(asd)
[1] "654"
> get_num(asd1)
[1] "65421"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
library(stringr)
val <- str_extract_all(asd1, "\\d+")[[1]]
tail(val, 1)
"65421"
```

OR

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]+", "", asd, perl=TRUE))
val <- regmatches(asd1, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", asd1))[[1]]
tail(val, 1)
"65421"
```

Answer (score 0):

If string always ends with digits, then we can try `gsub`

```
> x <- c("asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf654", "asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf65421")

> gsub(".*\\D", "", x, perl = TRUE)
[1] "654"   "65421"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `stri_extract_last_regex` from `stringi`

```
> library(stringi)
> stri_extract_last_regex(asd, "\\d+")
[1] "654"
> stri_extract_last_regex(asd1, "\\d+")
[1] "65421"
```