# Extract numbers and operators from a given string

Tags: r, gsub

I have a vector like this:

```
 vec <- c("a + 17", "äÜ - 20*3")
```

There are different letters, numbers and operators. I want the get rid of the letters. Or, the other way around, to keep only the numbers and operators. Here is the result I am looking for:

```
 c("17", "-20*3")
```

I tried `gsub("[:alpha:]", "", vec)` but it doesn't work and I don't get why because `[:alpha:]` should remove any letters and then I should end up with the vector I am looking for. But this is not the case.

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings) but it didn't help me either.

Comment: What's the logic behind omitting the plus sign in your desired output?

Comment: @dufei mistake. Updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different approach using `gsub`:

```
x <- gsub("[^0-9+-/*]", "", vec)

c(as.numeric(x)[1], x[2])
```

output:

```
[1] "17"    "-20*3"
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: This is magic :D Now I don't get why it didn't work before what I tried.. Why can we put characters like `+` without escaping? I thought `+` would mean one or more and not plus sign.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to run `x <- sub("^\\+", "", x)` instead of calling as.numeric() with NA warnings?

Comment: `gsub("[^0-9+-/*]", "", "a+")` gives `"+"`, so the `+` obviously actually means "look for the plus sign". That surprises me because I thought it would mean "one or more"..

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius. I get `[1] "17"       "-20*3+-2"` using your approach?!

Comment: @IngoPingo. You are right: `"+", "-", "*", and "/"` inside ***square brackets*** match those operators.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve it via `gsub`, but your regexp was wrong. Try to apply the next one:

```
vec <- c("a + 17", "djdj - 20*3 + äÜ - 2")
vec <- gsub("[[:alpha:]]+", "", vec)  # remove one or more letters
vec <- gsub("\\s+", "", vec)  # remove whitespace
```

or even

```
gsub("[^0-9\\*\\+\\-\\/]+", "", vec)  # remove all that isn't a number, minus, divide, times, plus or whitespace
```

Comment: @IngoPingo, the first one regexp doesn't, yes, but the second one removes, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-regex approach. Starting with your vector:

```
vec  <- c("a + 17", "äÜ - 20*3")
```

First, define a list of allowed characters:

```
good <- c(0:9, "+", "-", "*", "/", "^")
```

Then, split your vectors to character elements and only retain the ones that intersect:

```
vec <- lapply(strsplit(vec, ""), \(x) x[x %in% good])
```

Finally - join the elements together:

```
vec <- sapply(vec, paste0, collapse="")

vec
[1] "+17"  "-20*3"
```

Comment: Creative! Didn't have the idea to use strsplit() +1