# How to remove a string using stringr::str_remove_all?

Tags: regex, stringr

Here is the data I have:

```
X <- c("9 % vol.", "6.5 % vol.", "8.5 % vol.", "10 % vol.", "7.5 % vol.")
```

I want to turn X into a numeric vector looking like:

```
9, 6.5, 8.5, 10, 7.5
```

I tried the following code:

```
stringr::str_remove_all(x, "[ //%//vol.]")
```

But, this code gives me the following outcome:

```
[1] "9"  "65" "85" "10" "75"
```

How can I modify this code so that I get the output I want? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting numbers from vectors of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**modify your code to:**

```
stringr::str_remove_all(X, "( % vol.)")
```

**output would be:**

```
"9"   "6.5" "8.5" "10"  "7.5"
```